# MySQL table isn't updated but PHP echos a record added

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Tried everything, yet nothing seems to work. I even have two similar pages and the other inserts and updates just fine but this has been giving me sleepless nights.

After filling form entries and submitting, there's a confirmation that the record has been added but nothing is inserted into the database table. This is supposed to be part of an app for a clinic to deal with maternity/anc/pnc but this problem affects only the anc files. The pnc part of it works pretty well.

I'm certain you guys can help me see exactly what I'm not doing right and I truly would appreciate any assistance. Right or wrong.

First here's the file that's supposed to insert the records, called submitanc.php:

```
@$cid= $_POST["cid"];
 @$card= $_POST["card"];
 @$date= $_POST["date"];

 @$doctor= $_POST["doctor"];
 @$riskfactor= $_POST["riskfactor"];
 @$cycle= $_POST["cycle"];
 @$lmp= $_POST["lmp"];
 @$edd= $_POST["edd"];
 @$gestationage= $_POST["gestationage"];
 @$visit= $_POST["visit"];
 @$parity= $_POST["parity"];
 @$bp= $_POST["bp"];
 @$height= $_POST["height"];
 @$weight= $_POST["weight"];
 @$gestation= $_POST["gestation"];
 @$fhh= $_POST["fhh"];
 @$sickling= $_POST["sickling"];
 @$hb= $_POST["hb"];
 @$hb36wk= $_POST["hb36wk"];
 @$vdll= $_POST["vdll"];
 @$pmtct= $_POST["pmtct"];
 @$arv= $_POST["arv"];
 @$tt= $_POST["tt"];
 @$itw= $_POST["itw"];
 @$ipt= $_POST["ipt"];
 @$referredto= $_POST["referredto"];
 @$diagnosis= $_POST["diagnosis"];
 @$remark= $_POST["remark"];

 require_once 'conn.php';

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
   switch ($_POST['submit'])
   {
     case 'Add Record':
      if (Trim($card) != "" and Trim($date) != "")
      {
        $query_insert = "Insert into `anc` (`Card Number`, `Date`, `Physician`, `Risk Factor`, `Cycle`, `LMP`, `Edd`, `Gestation Age`, `Visit`, `Parity`, `BP`, `Height`, `Weight`, `Gestation`, `FHH`, `Sickling`, `HB@Reg`, `Temp`, `VDLL`, `PMTCT`, `ARV`,`TT`,`IPT`,`ITW`,`Referred To`,`Diagnosis` `Remark`,`SFH`,`HIV`,`Hep B`,`PH`,`Urine`,`Presentation`,`Lie`) 
                                      VALUES ('$card', '$date', '$doctor', '$riskfactor', '$cycle', '$lmp', '$edd', '$gestationage', '$visit', '$parity', '$bp', '$height', '$weight', '$gestation', '$fhh', '$sickling', '$hb', '$temp', '$vdll', '$pmtct', '$arv','$tt','$ipt','$itw','$referredto','$diagnosis', '$remark','$sfh','$hiv','$hepb','$ph','$urine','$presentation','$lie')"; $result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert);
```

And here, I know its crazy, but this is the form page, called anc.php:

```
<form action="submitanc.php" method="post">
<fieldset id="fieldset">
<legend><b><font size="2" face="Tahoma" color="green">Ante-Natal Basics</font></b></legend>
<div align="left">
<TABLE width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' align='center' bordercolor="#005B00" id="">
  <tr>
      <td width="20%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Date of Visit:</font></b>
      </td>
      <td> 
       <input type="hidden" size="20" name="card" value="<?php echo $card; ?>">
       <input type="hidden" size="20" name="cid" value="<?php echo $idx; ?>">
<?php
if (!$idx)
{ ?>
       <input id="inputField" type="text" size="20" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
<?php
} else 
{ ?>
       <input id="inputField" type="text" size="20" name="date" value="<?php echo $srow['Date']; ?>">
<?php } ?>
      </td>
      <td width="20%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Name of Doctor/Midwife:</font></b>
      </td>
      <td> 
       <input type="text" size="20" name="doctor" value="<?php echo $srow['Physician']; ?>">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Major Risk Factor:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td colspan='3'>
       <textarea cols="40" rows="3" name="riskfactor"><?php echo $srow['Risk Factor']; ?></textarea>
     </td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="fieldset">
<legend><b><font size="2" face="Tahoma" color="green">Menstrual History</font></b></legend>
<div align="left">
<TABLE width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' align='center' bordercolor="#005B00" id="">
   <tr>
     <td width="20%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Cycle:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="cycle" value="<?php echo $srow['Cycle']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="20%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Last Mentrual Period (L.M.P):</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="lmp" value="<?php echo $srow['LMP']; ?>">
     </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Expected Delivery Date (E.D.D):</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="edd" value="<?php echo $srow['EDD']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Gestation Age at Booking:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="gestationage" value="<?php echo $srow['Gestation Age']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
</TABLE>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#dcdfdf" width="100%" id="AutoNumber1"> 
<?php
 echo "<TR bgcolor='#9ff4ae'><TH><b><u>LMP </b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>EDD </b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>EGA to Date</b></u>&nbsp;</TH></TR>";
 $querya="SELECT `ID`,`Card Number`,`Date`,`LMP`,`EDD`,`Gestation Age` FROM `anc` WHERE `Card Number`='$card' order by `Date` desc";
 $resulta=mysql_query($querya);
 while(list($idx,$cart,$date,$lmp,$edd,$ega)=mysql_fetch_row($resulta))
 {
  echo "<TR><TH><a title='Click on this to amend it' href = 'anc.php?idx=" . $idx . "&card=" . $cart . "&dat=" . $date . "'>$lmp </a>&nbsp;</TH><TH> $edd &nbsp;</TH><TH>$ega &nbsp;</font></TH></TR>";
 }
?>
  </table>
</fieldset>

<fieldset id="fieldset">
<legend><b><font size="2" face="Tahoma" color="green">Ante-Natal Examination</font></b></legend>
<div align="left">
<TABLE width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' align='center' bordercolor="#005B00" id="">
  <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Blood Pressure:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="bp" value="<?php echo $srow['BP']; ?>">
     </td>
      <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Parity:</font></b>
      </td>
      <td> 
       <input type="text" size="20" name="parity" value="<?php echo $srow['Parity']; ?>">
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Weight:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="weight" value="<?php echo $srow['Weight']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Temperature:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="temp" value="<?php echo $srow['Temp']; ?>">
     </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Visit:</font></b>
      </td>
      <td> 
       <select size="1" name="visit">
        <?php
     echo '<option selected>' . $srow['Visit'] . '</option>';
         echo '<option>New Visit</option>';
         echo '<option>Returning Visit</option>';
        ?>
       </select>
      </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Height:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="height" value="<?php echo $srow['Height']; ?>">
     </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Gestational Age:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="gestation" value="<?php echo $srow['Gestation']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">SFH:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="sfh" value="<?php echo $srow['SFH']; ?>">
     </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Sickling:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="sickling" value="<?php echo $srow['Sickling']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Hb:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="hb" value="<?php echo $srow['HB@Reg']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">HIV:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="hiv" value="<?php echo $srow['HIV']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Hep B:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="hepb" value="<?php echo $srow['HepB']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">PH:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="ph" value="<?php echo $srow['PH']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Urine:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="urine" value="<?php echo $srow['Urine']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Presentation:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="presentation" value="<?php echo $srow['Presentation']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Lie:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="lie" value="<?php echo $srow['Lie']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">FHR:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="fhh" value="<?php echo $srow['FHH']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Sickling:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="sickling" value="<?php echo $srow['Sickling']; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">VDLL:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="vdll" value="<?php echo $srow['VDLL']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">PMTCT:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php
          $sqlv2 = "SELECT `val`,`type` FROM `booln` ORDER BY `type` desc";
          $result_v2 = mysql_query($sqlv2,$conn) or die('Could not list; ' . mysql_error());
          $v2=$srow['PMTCT'];
          while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_v2)) 
          {
           echo ' <input type="radio" class="radio" align="left" id="v2_' . $rows['val'] . '" name="pmtct" value="' . $rows['val'] . '" ';
           if ($rows['val'] == $v2) 
           {
             echo 'checked="checked" ';
           }
           echo '/>' . $rows['type'] . "\n";
          }
        ?>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">ARV:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="arv" value="<?php echo $srow['ARV']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">TT:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="tt" value="<?php echo $srow['TT']; ?>">
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">ITW:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="itw" value="<?php echo $srow['ITW']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="10%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">IPT:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
        <?php
          $sqlv2 = "SELECT `val`,`type` FROM `booln` ORDER BY `type` desc";
          $result_v2 = mysql_query($sqlv2,$conn) or die('Could not list; ' . mysql_error());
          $v2=$srow['IPT'];
          while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result_v2)) 
          {
           echo ' <input type="radio" class="radio" align="left" id="v2_' . $rows['val'] . '" name="ipt" value="' . $rows['val'] . '" ';
           if ($rows['val'] == $v2) 
           {
             echo 'checked="checked" ';
           }
           echo '/>' . $rows['type'] . "\n";
          }
        ?>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="15%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Refered To:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="referredto" value="<?php echo $srow['Referred To']; ?>">
     </td>
     <td width="15%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Diagnosis:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td>
       <input type="text" size="20" name="diagnosis" value="<?php echo $srow['Diagnosis']; ?>">
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="14%">
        <b><font face="Verdana" style="font-size: 9pt">Remark:</font></b>
     </td>
     <td colspan='3'>
       <textarea cols="40" rows="3" name="remark"><?php echo $srow['Remark']; ?></textarea>
     </td>

</tr>
<tr>
     <td width="10%">
<?php
if (!$idx)
{ ?>
     <input type="submit" value="Add Record" name="submit">
<?php
} else 
{ ?>
     <input type="submit" value="Update Record" name="submit">
<?php } ?>
     </td>
   </tr>
</TABLE>
</form>
 </fieldset>
<fieldset style="padding: 2">
<legend><b><font size="2" face="Tahoma" color="green">History of ANC</font></b></legend>
<b><font color="#FF0000" style="font-size: 8pt"><?php echo $tval ; ?></font></b>
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse" bordercolor="#dcdfdf" width="99%" id="AutoNumber1"> 
<?php
 echo "<TR bgcolor='#9ff4ae'><TH><b><u>Date of Visit </b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>Weight </b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>BP</b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>SFH </b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>Urine </b></u>&nbsp;</TH><TH><b><u>FHR </b></u>&nbsp;</TH></TR>";
 $query="SELECT `ID`,`Card Number`,`Date`,`Weight`,`BP`,`SFH`,`Urine`,`FHR` FROM `anc` WHERE `Card Number`='$card' order by `Date` desc";
 $result=mysql_query($query);
 while(list($idx,$cart,$date,$wt,$bp,$sfh,$urine,$fhr)=mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
  echo "<TR><TH><a title='Click on this to amend it' href = 'anc.php?idx=" . $idx . "&card=" . $cart . "&dat=" . $date . "'>$date </a>&nbsp;</TH><TH> $wt &nbsp;</TH><TH>$bp &nbsp;</font></TH><TH>$sfh &nbsp;</TH><TH>$urine &nbsp;</TH><TH>$fhr &nbsp;</TH></TR>";
 }
?>
  </table>
 </fieldset>
```

Comment: Get rid of these @, please.

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` tell you? Also - there's nothing in the code to echo out whether something has been added or not.

Comment: Check the value of `$result_insert`. If it's false, `echo mysql_error()` to see the reason.

Comment: I know this is not the route of your cause. That being said, I believe it's important to note that you have a massive case of invalid HTML markup. You're using deprecated tags in HTML 4 and in some cases tags that have been removed in HTML 5. As a heads up, you should **not** design a layout with tables unless the data you're displaying is actually tabular data. You should use a combination of semantic elements like `<div>`, `<span>`, `<section>` etc. and CSS to create your layouts. As far as the PHP goes, you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`. `mysql` extensions are **no longer supported**.

Comment: @War10ck thanks for point out the design flaws. I actually inherited the layout from a colleague and as we speak, I'm recreating it. I'm just anxious to get the codes working first before casting all the table tags away ;)

Answer (score 0):

its better to use

```
mysql_escape_string($_POST['fieldname']);
```

and echo that query and check in `mysql`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_insert = "Insert into `anc` (`Card Number`, `Date`, `Physician`, `Risk Factor`, `Cycle`, `LMP`, `Edd`, `Gestation Age`, `Visit`, `Parity`, `BP`, `Height`, `Weight`, `Gestation`, `FHH`, `Sickling`, `HB@Reg`, `Temp`, `VDLL`, `PMTCT`, `ARV`,`TT`,`IPT`,`ITW`,`Referred To`,`Diagnosis` `Remark`,`SFH`,`HIV`,`Hep B`,`PH`,`Urine`,`Presentation`,`Lie`) 
                                  VALUES ('$card', '$date', '$doctor', '$riskfactor', '$cycle', '$lmp', '$edd', '$gestationage', '$visit', '$parity', '$bp', '$height', '$weight', '$gestation', '$fhh', '$sickling', '$hb', '$temp', '$vdll', '$pmtct', '$arv','$tt','$ipt','$itw','$referredto','$diagnosis', '$remark','$sfh','$hiv','$hepb','$ph','$urine','$presentation','$lie')"; $result_insert = mysql_query($query_insert);

$res=mysql_query($query_insert);
if(!$res){
die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
//Confirm success with the username
 echo '<p><b>Your MSG</b></p>';
         }
```

then give the successfull msg . and figure where its goin wrong

Comment: Hello Black, I just added your code and it throws this error:


`Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Remark`,`SFH`,`HIV`,`Hep B`,`PH`,`Urine`,`Presentation`,`Lie`) ' at line 1`


What do I do next?